# How to find position of value in array?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
public void setning()
{
   var sentence = "THEWEAKCANNEVERFORGIVEFORGIVENESSISANATTRIBUTEOFTHESTRONG";
   char bokstav;

   for(int i = 0; i<sentence.Length;i++)
   {
      bokstav = sentence[i];
       Array.Find(chars,bokstav);
   }
}
```

The array `chars[]` has every letter from A-Z in positions 0 to 25. 
I am trying to get the number of the position of every letter in this sentence. How do I do this?

Edit: This is a morse code converter. I am trying to find the number so I can get the equivalent morse code of the letter.

This is the morse array:

```
string[] morse = new string[36]{".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..","-----",".----","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----."};
```

Edit: Solved it! Amateur mistake. Thanks everyone

Comment: `Array.IndexOf` or `String.IndexOf`

Comment: Does the numbers arrange in array on the same order as the letters ? A = 0, B = 1 ?

Comment: Yes they do. I am also trying to use Array.IndexOf, but it only returns -1 repeatedly

Comment: Then show your `chars` array and initialization...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an array for that, you can use the ASCII table values of those characters.

A simple **Subtraction** will produce you the numbers you're looking for.

```
foreach (char c in sentence)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} in Morse code is: {1}", c, morse[c - 'A']);
}
```

Comment: I need the number because I have another array called "morse[]" with morse code equivalents. I am trying to covnert the sentence into morse code

Comment: You should have specify it, can you show us the `morse` array ?